# Parse Issue in XCode 10.1 - 'Expected a type' occur in 'BraintreeDropIn' pod

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am using XCode 10.1 and I have installed pod 'BraintreeDropIn' for PayPal integration. But getting Parse issue as 'Expected a type' in 'BTAppSwitch.h' file as shown in the below screenshot.

Can you please someone explain to me why I get this error.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol BTAppSwitchHandler
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
#pragma mark - BTAppSwitch
@interface BTAppSwitch : NSObject
```

[image]

Comment: It works fine in Xcode 11.3.1. Unable to reproduce

Comment: Did you contact the developer of this pod?

Comment: Why are you using Xcode 10? In just over a month, Apple won't even be accepting apps built with Xcode 10.

Comment: @Rudedog There could be several reasons. For instance, I am still using Xcode 10 because my Mac is too old for version 11.

Comment: Running into this same issue. Has anyone found a workaround? I am on Xcode 10.3